# R: How to flag observations within a certain timeframe in data.table?

Tags: r, time-series, data.table

I'm working with a large data frame similar to the one below. I'd like to flag all observations that have an observation 30 days earlier by ID. I had originally been trying to do a fuzzyjoin to achieve this, but can't seem to nail down where I'm going wrong with {data.table}. Any tips?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
df<-tibble(
  date=sample(seq(as.Date('1999/01/01'), as.Date('1999/06/01'), by="day"), 300,replace=T),
  id=sample(seq(1:3),300,replace=T),claim_id=1:300)

df%<>%data.table()
df_index<-df
df_readmit<-df
names(df_index)[c(1,3)]<-c("index_date","index_id")
names(df_readmit)[c(1,3)]<-c("readmit_date","readmit_id")

df_readmit[df_index,.(id,index_date,readmit_date,index_id,readmit_id),
           on=.(id,readmit_date>index_date),nomatch=0]
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by flag and what you mean by *have an observation 30 days earlier*. Does that mean an observation which is from 30 days earlier than some later observation?

Comment: @sindri_baldur specifically, if an ID has an observation, create a new row that indicates whether that same ID had an observation 30 days earlier. I'd like to cut out any observations for individuals that have a prior observation within 30 days.

Comment: ***All*** observations have another one (same `id`) within 30 days (except the first row for each `id`, that is).

Comment: Think about this when formulating your question.  Let's say a ID has an observation on day 1, 27, 38, 67, ...  How does one decide which to exclude?  For example, as soon as one decides to include day 1, one must exclude day 27, include day 38, and exclude day 67.  On the other hand one could include days 27 and 67, ...  It will probably make a huge difference if you start with the most recent and work back - compared to starting with the oldest and working forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order can be changed, then I suggest we just look at the `diff` of the dates.

```r
library(data.table)
setorder(df, date)
df[,.SD[c(TRUE, diff(date) > 30),], by = id]
#       id       date claim_id
#    <int>     <Date>    <int>
# 1:     1 1999-01-01      231
# 2:     2 1999-01-02      284
# 3:     3 1999-01-03       78
```

In this case, because 100 days spanning 6 months is very unlikely to have a 30-day span untouched, none of the sample data has such an occurrence. However, perhaps the method works for you with your real data.